# SciTE Auto Save Temporary File

Tags: data-recovery, editors, parted-magic, scite

I was running an application that seemingly froze the GUI of my Linux distro. After a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> I got back to a terminal and reloaded the GUI.

However, even with the below User Options settings, when I reloaded SciTe, I didn't get my session restored, but more importantly the unsaved data since last save (On account of file being stored on removable storage that was temporarily unplugged) seems to be gone. Is there no temporary file that SciTE maintains in my home directory of unsaved changes??

```
save.on.timer=30
save.on.deactivate=1
load.on.activate=1
are.you.sure.on.reload=1
reload.preserves.undo=1
top.filters=$(all.files)All Source|$(source.files)
max.file.size=5000000
temp.files.sync.load=1
save.check.modified.time=1
save.session=1
save.recent=1
save.position=1
save.find=1
session.folds=1
session.bookmarks=1
highlight.current.word=1
view.eol=1
toolbar.usestockicons=1
find.close.on.find=0
find.in.files.close.on.find=0
```